# Can my maven project import dependencies from a pom inside a dependency?

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, maven-plugin, dependency-management

I have a maven project say "MyProject" that uses another project as an ordinary maven dependency say "MyDependency" which I wrote. MyDependency is a maven project that uses other dependencies such as springframework, apache-commons, apache-camel, etc.

The problem is this. I want MyProject to see the transitive dependencies inside MyDependency without having to add them again to the pom file. I tried both the maven-dependency plugin and the maven-jar plugin to generate a jar, as below, that contains all the dependencies within it, but with no result.

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.5.1</version>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <includeScope>compile</includeScope>
            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes/lib</outputDirectory>
            <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
            <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
            <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
</executions>
```

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.6</version>
<configuration>
    <archive>
        <manifest>
            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
        </manifest>
        <manifestEntries>
            <Class-Path>lib/</Class-Path>
        </manifestEntries>
    </archive>
    <finalName>core-${project.version}</finalName>
</configuration>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>jar</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
</executions>
```

Is there any way to do this? or is my question all wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "I want MyProject to see the transitive dependencies"? If you haven't done anything out of the ordinary, this should work out of the box.

Comment: Yes I know its supposed to work by default but that's not what is actually happening.

Comment: Are you using any particular scope for `MyDependency`?

Comment: @BurhaanAdam Do you mean you want an archive with all dependencies ? Or you can't write code because dependencies are not detected by your IDE and you can't access to classes ?

Answer (score 2):

MyProject can use the dependencies in MyDependency. Maven automatically resolves transitive dependencies. You don't need to do any copying. You can see the whole list of artifacts that are used by your project by using `mvn dependency:list`.